# What does the message "unreachable entry point" mean?

Tags: frama-c, program-slicing

I have a file containing several ACSL assertions (`file.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo()    {
  int a=0;
  //@ assert(a==0);
}

void print(const char* text)   {
    int a=0;
    //@ assert(a==0);
    printf("%s\n",text);
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])    {
    const char* a1 = argv[2];

    print(a1);
    foo();

    if (!a1)
      //@ assert(!a1);
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

I want to slice for all assertions with the command:

```
frama-c -slice-assert @all file.c -then-on 'Slicing export' -print -ocode slice.c
```

However, the slice does not look as expected (in fact it does not contain any of the functions contained in the files):

```
/* Generated by Frama-C */
typedef unsigned int size_t;
/*@ ghost extern int __fc_heap_status __attribute__((__FRAMA_C_MODEL__)); */

/*@
axiomatic dynamic_allocation {
  predicate is_allocable{L}(size_t n) 
    reads __fc_heap_status;

  }
 */
void main(void)
{
  char const *a1;
  return;
}
```

Instead I get output like this:

```
file.c:16:[kernel] warning: out of bounds read. assert \valid_read(argv+2);
[value] Recording results for main
[value] done for function main
file.c:16:[value] Assertion 'Value,mem_access' got final status invalid.
[slicing] making slicing project 'Slicing'...
[slicing] interpreting slicing requests from the command line...
[pdg] computing for function foo
[pdg] warning: unreachable entry point (sid:1, function foo)
[pdg] Bottom for function foo
[slicing] bottom PDG for function 'foo': ignore selection
[pdg] computing for function main
file.c:21:[pdg] warning: no final state. Probably unreachable...
[pdg] done for function main
[pdg] computing for function print
[pdg] warning: unreachable entry point (sid:5, function print)
[pdg] Bottom for function print
[slicing] bottom PDG for function 'print': ignore selection
```

What it going wrong here, in particular, what does `unreachable entry point`? Observation: If I change `argv[2]` to `argv[1]` I don't have these problems (but still get the warning in the first line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slicing needs to compute the PDG (Program Dependent Graph) which use the Value analysis results. The warning `unreachable entry point` means that, in the context you give, the function `foo` is not reachable (ie. it is called from unreachable statements).

Difficult to tell you more without an example...

---

EDIT:

In the ouput that you provided, notice the lines:

```
file.c:16:[kernel] warning: out of bounds read. assert \valid_read(argv+2);
```

and

```
file.c:16:[value] Assertion 'Value,mem_access' got final status invalid.
```

When the Value analysis meet an invalid property, it cannot go further. Because here the alarm comes from the first statement, everything else become unreachable. The invalid property is `\valid_read(argv+2);` since the default for the input context is to have a width of 2 for `argv`. This can be fixed either by using the option `-context-width 3`, or by using another entry point for the analysis (and specify it with `-main my_main`) that take no argument, define `argc` and `argv` explicitly, and call the real `main` with them.

An advice would be to use the slicing only after having checked if the Value analysis results are ok. You can run it alone with the `-val` option, and adjust other options if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been able to work out an illustrative example and edited (/refactored) my question accordingly.